# PacketFu capture within thread on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, debian, pcap

I've this little code using ruby packetfu library to capture packets:

```
require 'packetfu'

Thread.new {
   cap = ::PacketFu::Capture.new :iface => 'eth2', :promisc => true, :start => true, :filter => 'arp or icmp'
   cap.stream.each do |p|
       pkt = ::PacketFu::Packet.parse(p)
       puts pkt.peek
   end
}

sleep 120
```

This code runs perfectly on Debian 7, while on Ubuntu 14.04 can't capture any packets or not as many as I expect.

I really don't understand whats going on. Anyone has ideas or pointers to any difference between Debian and Ubuntu ruby stack or in the pcap library or whatever ?

On both system I installed the same packages:

```
apt-get install ruby ruby-dev libpcap-dev
gem install pcaprub
gem install packetfu
```

On Debian I have ruby 1.9.3p194 while on Ubuntu I have ruby 1.9.3p484.
On MacOS it works well as on Debian with ruby 1.9.3p545.

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention that removing Thread fixes the issue on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling ends up being a pcap bug in the libpcap-dev 1.5.3 package shipped in ubuntu 14.04.

Installing libpcap-dev 1.4.0 from a previous release fixed the issue.

I found a reference here: http://redmine.named-data.net/issues/1511

Comment: Hello. please tell me, just installing that other version of libpcap did the trick ? Or Maybe we need to reinstall the PacketFu gem ? I uninstall libcap, and I can still install PacketFu. Is it normal ?